# Как сделать поиск файлов не только в каталоге, но и в подкаталогах?

Tags: c++, winapi, файловая-система

Есть код, который просматривает файлы и папки в одном каталоге - но только в одном:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf = FindFirstFile((LPCSTR) "D:\\*", &FindFileData);
    wofstream fout("output.txt");
    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            fout << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

Как заставить его работать не только с каталогом, но и всеми его подкаталогами?

Comment: Когда находите каталог - рекурсивно ищите в нем...

Comment: Harry, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать. Или ссылку на какой-либо материал по теме киньте, если не сложно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот, что-то вроде

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void getFiles(const string& where)
{
    string mask = where + "\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf = FindFirstFile(mask.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName,".") == 0 ||
                    strcmp(FindFileData.cFileName,"..") == 0) continue;
                getFiles(where + "\\" + FindFileData.cFileName);
            }
            else
                cout << where << "\\" << FindFileData.cFileName << endl;

        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }
}


int main()
{
    getFiles("D:");
}
```